# Samsung Galaxy S No Unlock Screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, lock-screens

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (with [DMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Multimedia_Broadcasting)).

It's running Gingerbread and it doesn't have an unlock screen. I have tried to set it up through the settings but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I am not familiar with DMB, what is that?  What happens when you access the security settings? Does it appear to work, but then when you test it out it does not?

Comment: DMB is DAB and Online TV, it lets me set the lock but it just dosent work when i wake the galaxy up.

Comment: Have you changed the lock timeout in the security settings?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots showing your lock settings?

Comment: I dont need help anymore, i did a factory reset and it started working. I guess someone had changed something before  i got it! :)